# How to wrap text around image in MVC cshtml file?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

HTML

```
 <div><img src="~/images/phone.png" alt="Telefoon">010 - 264 44</div>
 <div><img src="~/images/mail.png" alt="Telefoon">info@thecons.com</div>
 <div><img src="~/images/vcard.png" alt="Telefoon">Download vCard </div>
```

Currently this HTML code makes the image and the text move to the right away from the position of the text above. I'd like to keep them on the same position by wrapping the text so that nothing gets moved and everything stays in position. But I can't access align="left" in my Visual Studio CSHTML file. How can I stop the elements from to the right? Is it the image size that's perhaps making them move to the right?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0oY6.jpg This is what I want to prevent

Comment: Sir like I said align isn't showing up in my img html tag

Comment: The align doesn't show up when I type it in the img tag in Visual Studio cshtml file..

Comment: it doesn't cause it is depreciated, need to use style equivalent

Comment: add this style `.floatImage{
    float:right;
    margin:10px;
}` then in your image `<img class="floatImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif">`

Comment: It works. Thank you. I have an issue with the image sizes though I need images that are the same size. How can I make all images the same size? Any tool?

Comment: @JohnReagan are you kidding me? read more about css and html.. create a class and give a height and width and assign it to every img..